# Address on IIS Change After Login on My Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to know, why my address changes automatically when I publish to IIS.

This is the address that shows the login page:

```
localhost/Travel
```

After login my address changes to

```
localhost/Admin/Index.aspx  = > this shows error page not found
```

So I add Travel before /Admin

```
localhost/Travel/Admin/Index.aspx = > OK
```

My question is why is `Travel` gone after I login?

This my login code :

```
if (txtuname.Value == DU.Username && txtpass.Value == DU.Password && DU.Role == "User")
{
    Session["Username"] = DU.Username;
    Session["Nama"] = DU.Nama;
    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
else if (txtuname.Value == DU.Username && txtpass.Value == DU.Password && DU.Role == "Admin")
{
    Session["Username"] = DU.Username;
    Session["Nama"] = DU.Nama;
    Response.Redirect("../Admin/Index.aspx"); = > my login page in User/Login.aspx
}
else
{
    ShowMessage("Password/Username Salah !");
}
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect("../Admin/Index.aspx");`  indicates redirection to `Admin/Index.aspx` in parent directory. That's why it goes to `localhost/Admin/Index.aspx`. You should do `Response.Redirect("/Admin/Index.aspx");`

Comment: okay, i will try it, thanks for help..